# How to toggle CSS animation on PHP variable update?

Tags: php, html, css

So I've got this here function in PHP:

```php
$username = $password = $usernameError = $passwordError = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $usernameError = "Username invalid";
    } else {
      $username = check($_POST["username"]);
    }
```

I want to activate this CSS animation:

```css
#error {
 color = red;
 animation:error 2s 1;
 -webkit-animation:error 2s 1;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-delay: 4s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes error{
 from {opacity :1;}
 to {opacity :0}
}
@-webkit-keyframes error{
 from {opacity :1;}
 to {opacity :0}
}
```

When the variable $usernameError is changed from nothing to something, in the above example it is changed to "Username invalid"

For reference this is the html element the animation  is applied to:

```html
<span id="error">* <?php echo $usernameError;?></span>
```

Any suggestions for how to achieve this?

Comment: it is call in ajax? or the form will ne refresh in php?

Comment: You could add some (potentially inline) Javascript to listen for a change on your error element, that in turn triggers your css animation (by adding the id "error" for example)

Comment: So the PHP triggers in page when this form is submitted: <form name="login" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

Comment: That's a good idea Sven! You genius! I'm gonna try that

Comment: If you only need this after the form was submitted the regular way (no AJAX), then why don’t you simply trigger this animation via a class - that you either add to that element or not, in your PHP script …? I don’t see why this would need any JavaScript stuff like in the currently existing answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sven was actually really easy:

On my HTML element I added

```html
onchange="animate()"
```

Which makes it look like this:

```html
<span onchange="animate()" id="error">* <?php echo $usernameError;?></span>
```

The javascript code to toggle this animation was also fairly straight forward:

```js
element.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
function animate() {
 element.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
 setTimeout(function (), 5000);
 element.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
}
```

Comment: I doubt that all browsers will fire a change event for a span element.